# Increment column value based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd like to increment the values in the column `nc` by 1 each time the value in `10minDiff` changes. In the Table below, the values in `nc` should read 2 from row 1246 onwards and 3 the next time `10minDiff` changes from 10.

[image]

```sql
SELECT [Einspeiser/Netzbetreiber],     
       [Stufe%],  
       [Start], 
       [10minDiff],
       [nc] = IIF([10minDiff] = 10, 1, 0) 
FROM 
   (
   SELECT [Einspeiser/Netzbetreiber],      
          [Stufe%],      
          [Start],      
          [10minDiff] = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG([Start]) OVER (ORDER BY [Start]),
          [Start])
   FROM 
    (
            SELECT 'Merkur AC156' AS [Einspeiser/Netzbetreiber],
            [Stufe%] = ROUND([Active power demand setpoint] * 100 / 198, 2), 
            [TimeStampLocalSystem] AS Start
        FROM 
       (
           SELECT [Systemnumber],
           [TimeStampLocalSystem],
           [TimeStampUTCSystem],
           [Minute10Average],
           [Name]
         FROM [SCADACustomerHistorical].[dbo].[CV_English_ChannelData]
         WHERE [TimeStampLocalSystem] 
         BETWEEN 
        '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-03-31 23:50:00.000'
         AND [Systemnumber] IN ('1082704200')
         AND [Name] 
         IN 
         ('Active power demand setpoint', 
          'Actual active power', 
          'DMI power demand in MW', 
          'Active power reference setpoint')
       )temp_table
     PIVOT 
     (
      SUM(
      [Minute10Average])
       FOR 
       [Name] IN 
      ([Actual active power], 
       [Active power demand setpoint], 
       [DMI power demand in MW], 
        [Active power reference setpoint]
       )
      ) pivot_table
    )tbl2
   WHERE [Stufe%] <> 100
  ) 
 tbl3

ORDER BY [Start];
```

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation, instead of all left aligned text, and line breaks, really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: You mentioned a trigger in your title, do you *really* mean you want a `TRIGGER`? `nc` is derived by an expression in your query, so it being affected by a `TRIGGER` is impossible.

Comment: @Larnu I meant to effect a change, perhaps i should reword my question

Comment: so is the column `nc` an actual column in a table or just a calculated column in your result set ?

Comment: @GuidoG nc is a calculated column

Comment: @GuidoG I have edited the code

Comment: *"I have edited the code"* and gone back to left aligned >_< Please **format** your code...

Comment: Sample data as text would be helpful.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to find islands based on start times and 10minDiff length? So in a nutshell ordered by start time ascending with groups of minimum start times by 10minDiff?

Comment: @KnutBoehnert  Kind of, Each island stops when 10minDiff <>10, and (each row of the island) gets 1 assigned to it , the next island 2 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data is not textual.I am writing UnTested query.

```
create  table #temp(id int,t1minDiff varchar(20),t1nc int,t2id int)
insert into #temp
select t1.id,t1.10minDiff,t1.nc ,t2.id as t2id
from tabl11 t1
outer apply(select top 1 t2.id from tabl11 t2 where t2.id>t1.id 
and t1.10minDiff!=t2.10minDiff order by t2.id )oa

--in #temp t2id if not null that need to be updated with next increatment
--Select * from #temp (test this)

update t1
set nc=ca.nc+1
from tabl11 t1
inner #temp t2 on t1.id=t2.t2id
cross apply(select max(nc)nc from #temp t3 where t3.id<t2.t2id )ca

    drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this ?

| id | 10mindiff | nc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1238 | 10 | 1 |
| 1239 | 10 | 1 |
| 1240 | 780 | 0 |
| 1241 | 10 | 2 |
| 1242 | 10 | 2 |
| 1243 | 10 | 2 |
| 1244 | 369 | 0 |
| 1245 | 10 | 3 |
| 1246 | 10 | 3 |

If that is the case you can use a simple subquery to fetch the number of deviations from 10

```
declare @table1 table (id int, [10mindiff] int)
insert into @table1 values 
(1238, 10),(1239, 10),(1240, 780),(1241, 10),(1242, 10),(1243, 10),
(1244, 369),(1245, 10),(1246, 10)

select t.id,
       t.[10mindiff],
       case when t.[10mindiff] <> 10 then 0
            else 1 + (select count(1) from @table1 t2 where t2.id < t.id and t2.[10mindiff] <> 10)
       end as nc 
from   @table1 t
order by t.id
```

**EDIT**

The advantage if this method is that it does not matter in what order you fetch your data

Comment: Yes, but i have thousands of rows, ids

Comment: @OldNick Did you try it to see how it performs ?

Comment: @OldNick,if this work then it can be optmize and it is far better than writing lenghty,complicated and using so many window function.It will work ok in thousands of rows.